# Insert a string into a linked list

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program that takes a sentence from user input and stores that in a linked list. This is what I have done so far and it seems to be working except that when I print the list it prints the string and then goes into a infinite loop printing "garbage". Can you see where I have gone wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLENGTH 100

typedef struct node {
   char data;
   struct node *next;
} node;

int
main(void) {
   char str[STRLENGTH];
   printf("Enter a string: ");
   gets(str);

   node *linkedList = NULL;
   node *head = NULL;
   node *pre = NULL;

   int i;
   for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      linkedList = malloc(sizeof(node));
      if(str[i] == ' ')
         linkedList -> data = 0;
      else
         linkedList -> data = str[i];

      if(pre != NULL)
         pre -> next = linkedList;
      else
         head = linkedList;
      pre = linkedList;
   }

   while(head != NULL) {
      printf("%c", head -> data);
      head = head -> next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize `linkedList -> next` to `NULL`

Comment: @Kninnug Thanks! That worked fine! I didn't imagine the solution to be that easy...

Comment: Also: (1) never use `gets()`; (2) always check the return from `malloc()`; (3) `free()` your nodes at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize `linkedList -> next`, so it has a garbage value, which is not necessarily `NULL`. Therefore the `while` loop tries to follow it and accesses some random memory address (pointed to by `head -> next`) and causes *undefined behaviour*.

In addendum, don't use `gets`, it doesn't protect against overflow. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I added the initialization and it works as expected now! I also changed to "fgets" instead of "gets" to protect against overflow. The difference between "gets" and "fgets" would be that fgets knows the size of the array while "gets" don't if I understand it correctly?!

Comment: Indeed, `gets` is removed in C11 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug only occurs in the final iteration of the for-loop. You're not initialize the next pointer of the final element in the linkedList.

If you want to minimize the number of operations you're doing. After the execution of the for-loop and before the while-loop add

```
pre->next = NULL;
```

Since you know pre is going to point to the final node. This way, you won't do it every iteration of the loop.